# My Dog stares into my neighbours yard

Tags: dogs, training

My dog tends to stare over our backyard wall an look at my neighbours the whole day.

Its just weird because he will randomly be looking into their yard even when we call him.

Its not like my neighbour has any dogs or anything.

Any solutions or explanations

P.S. He is just over 1 year old

Edit: It just seems weird as he doesn't pay much attention to anything happening in my yard and he takes more interest in looking into their yard. Even if we are playing, he will randomly go to the wall and look that side

Comment: When did this start happening?

Comment: An explanation why you think this is a problem would be an improvement to the question.

Comment: Its been like this for about 4 - 5 months now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dogs have a better sense of smell than we do and better/different hearing (in my dog, it's selective, but that's another story).

The chances are that there's something that smells different in your neighbour's yard, or there are critters in there that are making sounds/smells that are attractive to your dog, but you don't notice.

This could be anything, but I'd guess it's critters that have set up home over there.  You might want to speak to your neighbour and see if they have a problem with pests/rats/whatever.

Comment: I'd like to add rabbits and squirrels to the critter list too.